# overriding message [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: spring-security, spring-ldap

I'm using Spring LDAP security to authenticate users. In my .jsp I have:

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
   <div class="errorText">${sessionScope['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].message}</div>
</c:if>
```

I was successful in overriding the default messages in Springframework/security and changed them from Bad credentials to Incorrect username/password.

**My problem:**
When I enter an invalid LDAP user I get a correct error message:

```
[LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name ''
```

**What I would like:** Override this message with a more user friendly one just as I have overridden the Bad credentials message.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you'll have to override the message for AuthenticationServiceException as well.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was thinking since the flow of looking up and authentication users goes to: LdapAuthenticationProvider which implements AuthenticationProvider and the authenticate method is the one throwing the exception. Thank you for replying.